# Globally replace a component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, native-base, babel-plugin-module-resolver

I have a React Native app with a fairly large codebase. I recently received a new requirement that requires me to add debounce functionality to all the buttons in the app. If I replace them with a custom component, it will result in a significant number of file changes. I tried configuring Babel's 'module-resolver', but it doesn't seem to be helping. Is there a better way to achieve this, or should I manually replace it everywhere?

Comment: Do you mean like add CSS? or a prop to these buttons?

Comment: You can always find and replace all in visual studio code in the "Search" tab. Or if you want to add CSS you can add in your CSS file at app level: button {/*your effect*/}

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but making significant changes to the files is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a shared component for your button or pressable it could be easily done ( that's the importance of having shared components, so that you can do changes globally in an effective way )
if not, there's a turnaround, you patch the library that you're using your buttons from ( react-native if you're using the common react native button ) and you add the debounce to the library so it will change globally and in the future too.
For patching you can use patch-package

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package
```

By patching I mean updating the package in node modules.